# iOS5 iPhone app not working on iOS6 iPad

Tags: ios5, ios6

Okay guys,

This is a weird one.

I have an iOS 5.1 iPhone application; Navigation based.

It works fine on the iOS 5.1 iPhone and iPad, and on the iOS 5.1 iPhone and iPad simulators.

Works fine on iOS 6 iPhone simulator.

On both the iOS 6 iPad and iOS 6 iPad simulator it does not work until you change the zoom level.

The UI comes up, but the buttons are not clickable. Changing the zoom makes everything work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: So are we :-( Looks like a bug in iOS 6. I'm opening a BugReport at Apple. Let's see what happens.

Comment: We've opened a BugReport at Apple. The problem occurs only if your application is landscape-only.

Comment: Had the same problem, was able to make a workaround based on this post: http://programmingthomas.wordpress.com/2012/10/08/keep-calm-v1-1-ios-6-ipad-bug/

Comment: Got a response from Apple today: "We have determined that this is a bug in iOS 6. Engineering is aware of the problem and has informed us that there are no workarounds, at the moment, other than the obvious solutions of the user pushing the 2x button, then 1x button or rotating the device, or starting your app in portrait and having the user rotate it to landscape."

Comment: Jeffery's workaround didn't work for me unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem with a piece of production code, managed to get around it using the same workaround given in the blog posted by Jeffrey

http://programmingthomas.wordpress.com/2012/10/08/keep-calm-v1-1-ios-6-ipad-bug/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the bound size for ipad [self.view setBounds: CGRectMake(0f, 0.0f, 768.0f, 1024.0)];